# Sharing a single repository location across users

Tags: git, github

Say I have a Linux box with three users: `main`, `A` and `B` and that they all have their own GitHub accounts (or equivalent git hosting solution) .

Say user `main` clones a repository from e.g. GitHub on the some location on the machine, and that `A`, `B` have full permissions to that location.

Can user `A` (or `B`) fully operate this repository (commit, pull, push, etc.) and have his/her changes recorded in the repository and on GitHub if they are coming from himself?

If so, what settings should the repository have (or not have) to have this work properly? Would this be possible by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can user `A` (or `B`) fully operate this repository (commit, pull, push, etc.)

Yes. If one has read/write access to a repo folder, all git operations are available.

- and have his changes recorded in the repository and on GitHub if they are coming from himself?

Yes, each commit being done as `A`, meaning `A` must have configured:

```
git config user.name A
git config user.email A@email.com
```

If `A` has [setup a gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/support/what-is-gravatar/), `A`'s profile picture will show up for each commits done by `A`.